# Rails: Foundation Zurb Tab doesn't work unless hard refresh in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation

I am using the foundation.tab.js library and I've noticed in production (Heroku) the tabs don't always respond. If I do a hard refresh they will come back and work as expected.

```
<dl class="tabs" data-tab>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1">Upcoming Events</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2">Past Events</a></dd>
</dl>


<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1">
  Standard Panel 1
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2">
  Standard Panel 2
  </div>
</div>
```

$(document).foundation(); is called at the end.

Any ideas why production might behave this way? I noticed it also happens with the foundation.orbit slider on Heroku.

Comment: This may be a Turbolinks issue. I recall having a similar issue a while back while hosting on Heroku. You can test if this is the case by disabling Turbolinks temporarily and seeing if the libraries can behave properly in production. If Turbolinks is indeed clashing with these libraries, then you can install the jquery-turbolinks gem, include that in your *app/assets/javascripts/application.js*, and then move *//= require turbolinks* to the bottom of the file. Not an ideal solution but this helped solve it for me.

Comment: Thanks Zoran, I tried jquery-turbolinks, but it was still acting a little funny on Heroku so I removed turbolinks completely and that did the trick. Foundation is working as expected in production.